# Make file environment variable not taking effect if called from shell script

Tags: c, bash, shell, makefile

Content of  test.sh shell script is below.

```
PATH=/root/toolchains/gcc/gcc-4.8.2-20140120-centos70/bin/:$PATH
make -C ~/apps
```

apps directory have a make file. Content is below.

```
all:
$(CC) -dumpversion
@echo $(PATH)
```

Here in make 'echo $PATH is showing new PATH variable. Here CC should pickup new cc from new path variable. But $CC is not picking from new path. Any pointers for this issue?

Comment: `CC` in make defaults to `cc`, are you sure you have a link named `cc` somewhere in your `PATH`?

Comment: echo $(CC) to see the path

Comment: $CC prints only 'cc'

Comment: add type -a $(CC) to see the paths for cc

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
PATH=/root/toolchains/gcc/gcc-4.8.2-20140120-centos70/bin/:$PATH
make CC=gcc -C ~/apps
```

Comment: With make CC=gcc option picking from new path, but my problem is not solved. I may have number of other tools(eg: LD) need to be picked from new path. Its not correct to pass all this as an option to make.

Comment: If those tools exist at `/root/toolchains/gcc/gcc-4.8.2-20140120-centos70/bin/` (e.g. `ld`), then they will be picked up first. I just imagined that you don't have a `cc` binary in `/root/toolchains/gcc/gcc-4.8.2-20140120-centos70/bin/`.

Comment: If you have further issues, please update your question or ask another one.